# How to merge value of key when I have a list-tuple object

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

This is my list-tuple object. It includes repeat and same keys are `a`.

```
a = [("a",1), ("b",3), ("a",5)]

dict_a = dict(a)

print dict_a
# {'a': 5, 'b': 3}
```

But I expect that I can get:

```
# {'a': 6, 'b': 3}
```

If I don't use `for` or `while` to solve, may I use built-in function to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a basic solution that would be better than a simple loop. This would be a worse solution:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

a = [("a",1), ("b",3), ("a",5)]

dict_a = dict(Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda a: a[0] * a[1], a))))

print dict_a
# {'a': 5, 'b': 3}
```

This can be made worse and be further simplified with a join:

```
dict_a = dict(Counter("".join(map(lambda a: a[0] * a[1], a))))
```

And further simplified should list compression not break the `for` rule:

```
dict_a = dict(Counter("".join(b[0] * b[1] for n in a))))
```

Shortened (sort of) if we import the multiply operator.

```
from operator import mul
dict_a = dict(Counter("".join(mul(*b) for b in a)))
```

Another terrible idea is to remove `Count` and use count, but it requies we use a variable.

```
b = "".join(mul(*b) for b in a)
dict_a = {e[0]: b.count(e) for e in b}
```

Although we could just iterate over `a` into a dict, counting as we go along:

```
from operator import itemgetter
dict_a = {e[0]: sum(map(itemgetter(1), filter(lambda a: a[0] == e[0], a))) for e in a}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would go for this solution:

```
import collections

dict_a = collections.defaultdict(int)
for k, v in a:
    dict_a[k] += v
```

But if you're really inclined to do so, here's a solution without a for/while loop :)

```
import collections

dict_a = collections.Counter(sum(map(lambda (x, y): (x,) * y, a), ()))
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, though the author did mention he didn't want to use a for or while loop.

Comment: @matthewatabet: I know, but I still recommend this :) The other solutions are actually all using loops too, they're just hiding it better ;)

Comment: yes, you're absolutely correct :) It was a fun bit of mental gymnastics trying to not directly use a loop... but practically speaking this answer is the easiest to read.

Comment: well, there you go :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built-in `map()` function and a partial:

```
from functools import partial


def accum(memo, key_value):
    key, value = key_value
    memo[key] = value + memo.get(key, 0)
    return key, memo[key]

a = [("a", 1), ("b", 3), ("a", 5)]

dict_a = dict(map(partial(accum, {}), a))

print dict_a
>>> {'a': 6, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: That's certainly a creative option, +1 from me :P

Answer (score 1):

```
def dict_sum(a, totals=defaultdict(int)):
    k, v = a.pop()
    totals[k] += v
    return totals if not a else dict_sum(a, totals)
a = [("a",1), ("b",3), ("a",5)]
res = dict_sum(a)
print res
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 6, 'b': 3})
```